# What is the name of this sort of Platform?

Tags: single-word-requests

[image: From Game of Thrones Season 1]

They are above the ground, below them their children are training. For some reason the word is escaping me.

Comment: Balcony.......?

Comment: Watch tower? Lookout?

Comment: "Deck" is what it would commonly be called in the US, though that term doesn't sound as sexy as "gallery" or "balcony".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to ELU, 312.

Perhaps '**gallery**' is the most appropriate word here, as the setting looks historical. Otherwise, I'd agree with Jan's 'balcony'.

**gallery** NOUN ... 2A balcony or upper floor projecting from an interior back or side wall of a hall or church, providing space for an audience or musicians. {[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gallery)}

A gallery is usually an interior feature:

**gallery** 3. countable noun ... A gallery is an area high above the ground at the back or at the sides of a large room or hall. {[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gallery)}

although not necessarily:

**Gallery** ... 2a : an outdoor balcony {[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gallery)}

Comment: Welcome back, Edwin.

Comment: Hi, Lawrence. Thank you. Compression fractures of the spine and anti-myeloma chemo largely a thing of the past now; the NHS is indispensable.

Comment: Edwin, welcome back from me also.

Comment: Hello! You're back :) What a lovely surprise! I was so worried, so glad your health issues are a thing of the past.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A It was really embarrassing that I could remember the names of most of the drugs, but not the names of most of the medical staff.

Comment: Well done to the medical team, and nurses, who took care of you. Big bear hug to them all and most of all  to you.